# How to implement plural form of cleverref package to reference a system of equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

Let's consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[%
            %dvipdfmx,%dvips,%
            %pdfborder = 0 0 1,
            baseurl= http://,
            colorlinks=true,%
           ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \label{eqs:system}
     \frac{d^2 x}{d t^{* 2}} &= \omega^2 x+2 \omega \dot{y}-G\left(\frac{m_1}{r_1^3}\left(x-x_1\right)+\frac{m_2}{r_2^3}\left(x+x_2\right)\right)  \\
   \frac{d^2 y}{d t^{* 2}}  &=\omega^2 y-2 \omega \dot{x}-G\left(\frac{m_1}{r_1^3} y+\frac{m_2}{r_2^3} y\right) \\
   \frac{d^2 z}{d t^{* 2}} &=-G\left(\frac{m_1}{r_1^3} z+\frac{m_2}{r_2^3} z\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

reference to \Cref{eqs:system}

\end{document}
```

I need the plural `Equations` instead of `Equation`.

[image]

Can you show how to set the plural of `\Cref` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is explained in the manual of `cleveref`, section 6 (page 9).

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
%\usepackage[super]{nth}%?
\usepackage[%
            %dvipdfmx,%dvips,%
            %pdfborder = 0 0 1,
            baseurl= http://,
            colorlinks=true,%
           ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\Crefname{pluralequation}{Equations}{Equations}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label[pluralequation]{eqs:system}
\begin{aligned}
  \frac{d^2 x}{d t^{* 2}} &=
    \omega^2 x+2 \omega \dot{y}-G\left(\frac{m_1}{r_1^3}(x-x_1)+\frac{m_2}{r_2^3}(x+x_2)\right)
  \\
  \frac{d^2 y}{d t^{* 2}} &=
    \omega^2 y-2 \omega \dot{x}-G\left(\frac{m_1}{r_1^3} y+\frac{m_2}{r_2^3} y\right)
  \\
  \frac{d^2 z}{d t^{* 2}} &=
    -G\left(\frac{m_1}{r_1^3} z+\frac{m_2}{r_2^3} z\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

reference to \Cref{eqs:system}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed some harmful `\left` and `\right` commands. The package `amsbsy` is automatically loaded, but you probably are better served with `bm`.

I commented out `nth`. Superscripting “th” is bad practice. It was fashionable in the Victorian age, later revived by some unknown developer of a well-known word processing software who probably liked it.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg. Any suggestions to write the ordinal numbers without using the `nth` package?

Comment: @Giuseppe The most common usage (except for users of that word processor) is to write first, second, third and so on for small numbers. For larger numbers write 42nd; 100th, 1234th. If you want to refer to the item number *n*, type `$n$th` or, maybe, `$n\,$th`. In this case the superscript would be utterly wrong.